# perl Win32::OLE ExportAsFixedFormat syntax for powerpoint

Tags: perl, powerpoint, win32ole

I have trouble using perl (strawberry) and win32::ole using powerpoint (from office2010)
to convert ppt(x) to pdf.

I can export to jpgs fine with Export function but the function [ExportAsFixedFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096%28v=office.12%29.aspx) has a quite obscure syntax and alwawys gives me 
`Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020011: "Does not support a collection"`.

this is a sample of what I am trying

```
    my $ppoint = Win32::OLE->new('PowerPoint.Application', 'Quit');
    my $Presentation = $ppoint->Presentations->Open("$infile") || die("Una +ble to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError()) ; 
    $Presentation->ExportAsFixedFormat("$outfile", 2, 2, "msoCTrue", "ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFir +st", "ppPrintOutputFourSlideHandouts", "msoFalse", "", "" , "", "Fals +e", "False", "False", "False", "False");
```

second parameter [ppFixedFormatTypePDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265637.aspx) should be 2

third param 'ppFixedFormatIntentPrint' should be 2

Can anyone suggest a working example?

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer from golemwashere:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint';
...
$Presentation->SaveAs("$outfile",ppSaveAsPDF, 1);
```

This works using powerpoint 2007 on windows 7, but the return value has to be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I solved using

`$Presentation->SaveAs("$outfile", 32);`

it was tricky finding that 32 = pdf format
and also $outfile needed foward slashes : / 
in path (with \ I got confusing errors).

Comment: You should use use `Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint;` for constants such as `ppFixedFormatTypePDF ` and either `File::Spec` or `Path::Class` for constructing paths or escape the slashes as in `"C:\\Users\\golemwashere\\Documents" etc.